# Handling non std::io::Error(s) while implementing std::io::Write?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm trying to implement `std::io::Write` over HTTP and I'm not sure how to handle errors that do not have a counterpart in `std::io::ErrorKind`.

Here's a short reproduction:

```
extern crate reqwest;

use std::io::Write;
use std::io::Result;

struct HttpClient {
    // Some configurations (compression, certificates, timeouts)
}

impl Write for HttpClient {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<usize> {
        let client = ::reqwest::Client::builder().build()?;
        let res = client.post("http://httpbin.org/post").body(buf).send()?;
        Ok(buf.len())
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

The compiler responds with 2 errors:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::io::Error: std::convert::From<reqwest::Error>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:12:22
   |
12 |         let client = ::reqwest::Client::builder().build()?;
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<reqwest::Error>` is not implemented for `std::io::Error`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<std::io::ErrorKind>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<std::ffi::NulError>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<std::io::IntoInnerError<W>>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<serde_json::error::Error>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<openssl::error::ErrorStack>>
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::io::Error: std::convert::From<reqwest::Error>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:13:19
   |
13 |         let res = client.post("http://httpbin.org/post").body(buf).send()?;
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<reqwest::Error>` is not implemented for `std::io::Error`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<std::io::ErrorKind>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<std::ffi::NulError>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<std::io::IntoInnerError<W>>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<serde_json::error::Error>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<openssl::error::ErrorStack>>
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

There's a couple of things I could do, but I'm not happy with either of them:

1. Use `map_err` to map `reqwest::Error` to `std::io::Error` - This is not always trivial. For example, how would I map `TooManyRedirects`? I could use `std::io::ErrorKind::Other` but it doesn't feel right.
2. Define my own error type `MyError` and implement `std::convert::From` for `reqwest::Error` to `MyError` and for `MyError` to `std::io::Error` - This raises the same concerns from before - not all errors are easily convertible.

Are there any other better options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `io::Error` is the *only* thing you can do because that's the contract that the trait requires. Everything else just boils down to details and ergonomics.

[`io::Error::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.new) accepts an [`io::ErrorKind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html) and something that can be converted into an `error::Error`.

I'd probably write a function that transforms your domain error into a `io::Error` by calling `io::Error::new` and then use this new function in `map_err` everywhere. I'd start by cramming everything into `ErrorKind::Other` until I found a reason that a specific Reqwest error should be something else.

Will your consumers really care about something specifically being too many redirects? By construction, the answer *must* be "no" because they might be operating on a `File` or a `TcpSocket`, neither of which have such a concept.

I don't believe I would create a wrapper error type in this case; I can't see how it would provide any value. It would require extra type annotations that you get "for free" with a function.

> This is not always trivial.

That is correct — gluing two wildly different pieces together sometimes doesn't line up exactly the way we want. That's part of what makes programming both exciting and terrible.